# Two monitors - One Button?

Tags: windows, windows-7, multiple-monitors

Dual Screen - how can you Turn on both screen when you turn on one (or primary)??

Comment: People use the power buttons on the monitor?

Answer (score 4):

There are master/slave socket strips like [this one](http://www.knuerr.com/web/en/index_e.html?products/distrip/distrip_masterslave.html~mainFrame). If you switch on/off the device plugged into the master socket, the slave devices are switched, too.

Answer (score 2):

Plug both monitors into a power strip, and then use the switch on the power strip. If you wish to further save power, feel free to plug your printers and other peripherals into the strip as well. This will also kill any vampire devices which are sucking down more electricity when idle than they say they are (which is more common than you''d think)